# Get substring with input by all parts of string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, substring

I'm trying to get sub-string from string:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "boat in sea" };

        string input1 = "boat";
        string input2 = "sea";

        foreach (var x in list)
        {
            string res1 = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(input1) + input1.Length);   

            string res2 = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(input2) + input2.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Res 1: " + res1 + "\nRes 2: " + res2);
        }
```

My current output:

```
Res 1: in sea
Res 2:
```

But my desired output:

```
Res 1: in sea
Res 2: boat in
```

but without `"sea in boat"` in list `List<string> list = new List<string>() { "boat in sea", "sea in boat" };`, but only with  `"boat in sea"` as above:  `List<string> list = new List<string>() { "boat in sea" };`

Comment: `in boat` is not part of the string `boat in sea`. Are you sure you're not trying to break this up further and check for the presence of each **word**?

Comment: @Obsidian Age Hello, yes sure, it was posted incorrect. I've edited question

Comment: what output do you expect from "boat in sea in boat"?

Comment: @ vasily.sib Hello, I've edited question, with input  `boat` I want get `in sea`, with input  `sea`, `boat in`

Comment: what if a word `boat` appears twice?

Comment: @ vasily.sib no in my case it does not appears twice

Comment: From what I understood, basically you want to replace your input string with a `string.Empty` and return the output. Make sense? So for input `boat` you would get " in sea". You can trim the whitespaces.

Comment: @ViktorArv, I can see, that in your case that word appears only once. But does this mean, that any word in `x` string will _always_ appears only once? If no, please, tell us what output do you expect from "boat in sea in boat" string. Also, what output you expect from "boatinsea" string (without spaces)?

Comment: This question is a bit open ended and unclear to me.  What happens here in the context of a larger text?  E.g. what happens if `boat` appears more than once in the source string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 2 to

```
string res2 = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(input2) - 1);
```

Also, you should handle the case when IndexOf returns -1 if string is not found.

Comment: Hello, I got exception  `an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.`

Comment: do you test your code? `x.Substring(0, input2.Length - x.IndexOf(input2))` in this case equals `x.Substring(0, 3 - 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach the solution in following manner:

```
string text = "boat in sea";
```

string[] textSplitted = text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmpty...);

Now textSplitted Array is like:
[0] = "boat", [1] = "in", [2] = "sea"

After you know your 2 Inputs (between which you got to find the sub-strings) - Its simple Search & concat with spaces.

Ex: Input1 = boat & Input2 = sea

Iterate over array and match for boat. If found then keep concatenating all strings in the array (with space in between) until you find Input2.
In this example - you will only get "in"

now the two results will be Input1 + " " + "in"  & "in" + " " + Input2

Comment: This is not a soultion at all. How do this handle if next string will be "pot on table"?

Comment: @vasily.sib - Well this is the Logic/Algorithm - I do not meant to HARD CODE "in". You should understand the post before Down Voting.

Comment: @vasily.sib - Do you want us to Post Actual Code solution here? Rather than giving "hints" so that OP can reach to/understand the solution.

Comment: As I can see from question, and as OP not pointed exactly, what output he expect, I assume that he is talking about _substrings_ (as from question title), so from "boaty in sea" expected output would be "y in sea". Your solution not handling this. But if @ViktorArv will return here and tell us that you somehow understand what he wants, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This `Linq` *thing* will remove the first occurence of a word inside a list of words.
As an option, it will remove all occurrences of a word inside the said list.

The `CheckList` array contains the words to remove:

```
string[] Words = new[] { "boat in sea", "cat on roof", "big bat on boat", "sea side boat ride" };
string[] CheckList = new[] { "boat", "sea", "cat" };

var result = Words.SelectMany(s => new[] {
    CheckList.Where(sub => s.Contains(sub))
             .Select(sub => s.Remove(s.IndexOf(sub), sub.Length).Trim()
    });
```

To remove all occurences, substitute the previous `Select()` with:

```
.Select(sub => s.Replace(sub, string.Empty))
```

Print the results (both methods print the same list, with the current selection of Words):

```
foreach (var StrippedLines in result)
{
    foreach (var s in StrippedLines)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------");
}

in sea
boat in
--------------
on roof
--------------
big bat on
--------------
sea side ride
side boat ride
--------------
```